# Vue.js: list of checkboxes that open more options

Tags: vue.js

I have some JSON data in a file, in this format:

```
[
    {
        "component": "events",
        "events": [
            "group_event",
            "close"
        ]
    },
    {
        "component": "heading",
        "events": [
            "action",
            "card_load",
            "card_new",
            "card_access",
            "logout",
            "reset",
            "list",
            "owndata",
            "status"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to find a way, using Vue, to

1. list every component next to a checkbox
2. after clicking one checkbox, the associated events would appear, each next to a checkbox

So far, I have something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="c in get_all_components()">
        <td><input :value="c.component" :name="c.component" type="checkbox" v-model="checkedBoxes">{{c.component}}</input></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I have tried listing the events, Vue keeps throwing error messages about 'undefined' variable 'c' (inside the `<tr>` element).

The goal is to manage to create objects of all the *chosen* components and all *their* chosen events

Here are a couple screenshots to visualize:

[Before clicking checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P1ip.png)

[After clicking checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reNPo.png)

If anyone could help me, it would be a huge help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first mistake is that you call `get_all_components()` like a function.
you have to call it like that `get_all_components`.

Here is an example how you can implement your goal.

```
 <div>
      <div v-for="c in all_components">
        <div><input type="checkbox" v-model="c.component.isChecked">{{c.component.value}}</input>
            <div v-if="c.component.isChecked">
                <div v-for="event in c.events">{{event}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the script:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            'all_components': [
                {
                    "component": {
                        "value": "events",
                        "isChecked": false
                    },
                    "events": [
                        "group_event",
                        "close"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "component": {
                        "value": "heading",
                        "isChecked": false
                    },
                    "events": [
                        "action",
                        "card_load",
                        "card_new",
                        "card_access",
                        "logout",
                        "reset",
                        "list",
                        "owndata",
                        "status"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

this way you manage the true/false in property called `isChecked`, and in case of true value, you render the events list.
goodLuck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try this ^_^

Comment: Marked it solved, thanks for taking the time to write such a good answer!